# Error while deleting cell array elements in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, cell, element

I have following 1-D cell array:

```
obj = {'HotAirBalloon' 'Cloud' 'Sun' 'Lightning'};
```

I trying to delete its elements using a `for` loop in the following manner:

```
for i = 1:4

obj (i) = [ ];

end
```

But, I am getting error:

> Index of element to remove exceeds matrix dimensions, and following elements remain in the 'obj' array: 'Cloud'    'Lightning'

If I repeat the operation (for loop), then the elements get deleted.

What's the problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need for a loop

```
obj(1:4) = [];
```

**Explanation of your code :**

When you use loop in the first iteration (`i = 1`) you have `obj(1) = [];`, then `obj` has `3` elements,

```
obj = { 'Cloud' 'Sun' 'Lightning'}
```

In the second iteration `obj(2)=[]` which is actually `obj(3)` (`sun`). So at the end of second loop:

```
obj = { 'Cloud' 'Lightning'}
```

In the third iteration you have `obj(3) = []` which exceeds dimension of `obj` and you get the error.

If you want to use loop you can use it like this,

```
for i = ones(1,4)
    obj(i) = [];
end
```

Comment: Or, `for i=1:4, obj(1)=[]; end` :-) but seriously, you're right, `obj(1:4)=[];` is best.

Comment: I discovered one more way to do this (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kKTMg3tn3J0), which is as follows:for i = 4:-1:1
obj (i) = [ ];
end